# Override whole function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've trying to build a spy function, I'm building a function that takes another function and overrides it. But I'm getting able to override it.

```
function spy(f: (...args: any[]) => any | void) {
    const g = f;
    const metadata: IMetadata = {
        calledCount: 0,
        calledWith: []
    }

    f = function (...prototypeArgs: any[]) {
        console.log('Hello from prototype')
        metadata.calledCount++
        metadata.calledWith!.push(prototypeArgs)
        return g(...prototypeArgs)
    }
    return Object.freeze(metadata)
}
```

And I'm testing it with this

```
const g = spy(f)
f()
f()
console.log(g)
```

But g is not changing because is not getting overrided.

```
{ calledCount: 0, calledWith: [] }
```

Comment: Because you are freezing the object, `Object.freeze(metadata)`.

Comment: I think that is was, but then I realize that the `console.log` inside the reassignment is not being called

Comment: Yeah, because the global `f` is not changing, only the local `f` variable is changing. please read JavaScript variable scoping.